# How can I find where the print called?

Tags: java, debugging, printing

I'm working on an old java application project using IntelliJ, the source code is huge. One class has a method which prints the info of video per frame while playing. I want to disable this code for printing but I have no idea where does it come from or what the class name is. It didn't show up when I searched the string directly. Is there a cleverer way to find where the print called?

(From comments):

Output line is `[isDeveloper true]------ get duration(=3.552653) is test impl ------`

Answer (score 5):

Replace `System.out` with your own `PrintStream`, using [`System.setOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-), have it match the (un-)desired output, put a break-point on the match clause, and look at the stack trace.

---

Since `PrintStream` has many, many methods, instead of overwriting all of the possible methods that may be called when generating the (un-)desired output, let's direct all the `PrintStream` output to a `FilterOutputStream` of our own devising; then we should only have to overwrite one method, but we will need to reconstruct our string.

Example:

```
class Prospector extends FilterOutputStream {

    int count = 0;

    private OutputStream original;

    public Prospector(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
        original = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        String buffer = new String(b, off, len, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        if (buffer.contains("]------ get duration(=")) {
            if (count == 0) {
                new Exception().printStackTrace(original);
            }
            count++;  // Set breakpoint here
        }
        super.write(b, off, len);
    }
}
```

When the program starts, install a new `PrintStream` wrapping the original in our `Prospector`:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new Prospector(System.out)));
```

Set a breakpoint on the indicated line.  When the program stops at the breakpoint, look up the stack trace to find the class/method which generates the output.

When the mystery class generates your target line, which may be like ...

```
System.out.format("[%s %s]------ get duration(=%f) is %s -------%n",
    "isDeveloper", "true", 3.552653, "test impl");
```

... this method may be called multiple times, with `buffer` contain the individual parts of the line, in succession.  In the above case, this would be:

- `"["`
- `"isDeveloper"`
- `" "`
- `"true"`
- `"]------ get duration(="`
- `"3.552653"`
- `") is "`
- `"test impl"`
- `" -------"`
- `"\n"`

Ideally, `]------ get duration(=` should be unique enough to find the class/method you are looking for, but you can adapt as needed.

It is also possible that the entire text is formatted into a single `String`, and printed out in one call.  This is why `.contains(...)` is used to match the required output.

Comment: I use `log4j` for the logs in the recent code, but for the old code(so huge, some are packed as a library) what should I do?

Comment: Have you found the print statements you’re looking for?  If not, provide some sample output lines, and I can help by crafting your required PrintStream object for you, so you can locate them.  But: “_I use log4j ... old code ... huge ... what should I do?_” sounds like it might be a new (albeit unclear) question, which should be in a different post.

Comment: Output line is `[isDeveloper true]------ get duration(=3.552653) is test impl -------` not idea where it comes from.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it, it does catch the relative output string, however, didn't work on the mystery output that confuses me. maybe because it's called from a 3rd library which makes it untraceable?

Comment: Add the following before the breakpoint: `new Exception().printStackTrace();`, and add the output to your question post, so we can see this “untraceable” call.  It could be that a native method is being used, or simply that the source code for the 3rd party library is not available.  But it should at least identify which library it is coming from.

Comment: It seems the mysterious output doesn't meet `if (buffer.contains("]------ get duration(="))` condition, so the exception is not printed, I've tried other keywords.

Comment: 20 hours ago, you said "_it does catch the relative output string_".  Why would it stop now?  Do you still have your breakpoint set?  Does that get triggered?   Is it the mysterious output on `System.out` or `System.err`?  If you've used `System.setErr(...)`, and you call `.printStackTrace()`, by default that goes to `System.err`, so you might be reentering the `PrintStream`, which may not work.  You can capture the original output stream, and use that in the `printStackTrace()` to ensure you avoid this.  See edit.

Comment: Sorry if I made it unclear, I meant `it does catch the relative output string, however, didn't work on the mystery output that confuses me.`, Prospector works with other output but not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: You do see the `if (count == 0) {...}` which will only print the stack trace the first time.  If you want to catch multiple, different messages, you’ll need to relax or rework that condition.

Comment: I print the stack trace in the whole `if(contains)` block, but it doesn't catch anything.

Answer (score 0):

i think

Pressing Ctrl+ Mouse click on required variable or method

acts as a hyperlink to source

should do the trick(on IntelliJ)

Comment: Well, the thing is I couldn't find that method nor class.